# Tag helper for create link is not works when I use AddPageRoute

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I use Razor pages.
I want to defined 2 routes for a razor page, so I use `AddPageRoute`

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Product", "/product/code-{productCode1}");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Product", "/product/code-{productCode1}/code-{productCode2}");
    });
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(int productCode1, int productCode2)
{
    return Page();
}
```

When I use second route for create link, everything is ok.

```
<a asp-page="/Product" asp-route-productCode1="6" asp-route-productCode2="18">link</a>
```

and result is:

```
https://localhost:1898/product/code-6/code-18
```

But if I want to use first route:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Product", "/product/code-{productCode1}");
```

```
<a asp-page="/Product" asp-route-productCode1="6" >link</a>
```

The tag helper not works and the href of the `a` tag is empty.

Any sugestion ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use only the first route:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Product", "/product/code-{productCode1}");
     
    });
```

Index:

```
<a asp-page="/Product" asp-route-productCode1="6" asp-route-productCode2="18">link</a>
<a asp-page="/Product" asp-route-productCode1="6">link</a>
```

result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, Thanks, but I don't like to query string (?productCode2=18). I want friendly URL like ```https://localhost:1898/code-6``` for first route, and for second: ```https://localhost:1898/code-6/code-18```, if I use your solution, the result URL will use query string: ```https://localhost:1898/code-6?productCode=18```

Comment: I think this situation is a razor pages bug. Check this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10691#issuecomment-499597910